# Is such a result possible with a query from an SQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb

I want to fire a query to get such a result:

```js
[{
  id: 1,
  brandName: "x"
  brandModels: [
    {id: 1, modelName: "abc", createdAt: "yyyy-mm-dd"},
    {id: 2, modelName: "def", createdAt: "yyyy-mm-dd"},
  ]
},
{
  id: 2,
  brandName: "y"
  brandModels: [
    {id: 4, modelName: "ghi", createdAt: "yyyy-mm-dd"},
    {id: 5, modelName: "jkl", createdAt: "yyyy-mm-dd"},
  ]
}]
```

**Tables Schema**

```
BrandsTable
{id, brandName, brand_id}

ModelsTable
{id, modelName, createdAt}
```

**I guess it's not possible like that?** I don't have any experience with text-based databases, but I can well imagine that this can be achieved with a MongoDB. Because ultimately I want to have a js object at the end of the day.

Comment: I can't post an answer while this question is closed, but the short answer is that you can do this in MySQL 5.7 and later using a combination of JSON_OBJECT() and JSON_ARRAYAGG().

Comment: @BillKarwin Thank you very much for your Comment! It sound very good. Since my answer was closed without comment, I assumed that it was not possible and have now built two queries that I put together programmatically. But the approach with JSON_OBJECT would really interest me. I see you can answer again :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example but I have not tested it:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
  JSON_OBJECT(
    'id', b.id,
    'brandName', b.brandName,
    'brandModels', m.modelArray
  )
) AS joined_result
FROM BrandTable AS b
JOIN (
    SELECT brand_id, JSON_ARRAYAGG(
      JSON_OBJECT(
        'id', id, 
        'modelName', modelName,
        'createdAt', createdAt
      )
    ) AS modelArray
    FROM ModelsTable
    GROUP BY brand_id
) AS m USING (brand_id);
```

Note that I had to assume the ModelsTable also contains a column for `brand_id`, otherwise there is nothing to use in the join condition.

Read documentation for [JSON_OBJECT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object) and [JSON_ARRAYAGG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) for more information about how these functions work.