# How to get all the child menu items as separate array under each category in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `menu_categories` and `menu`, I am trying to fetch data and getting results like this

```
    Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [category_name] => Settings
            [category_icon] => gear
            [menu_name] => Create settings
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [category_name] => Users
            [category_icon] => men-shape
            [menu_name] => Create user
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [category_name] => Settings
            [category_icon] => gear
            [menu_name] => Edit settings
        )
)
```

How can I have menu as array like below using just `sql query` without `php`

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [category_name] => Settings
            [category_icon] => 
            [whole_menu_table_as_array] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [menu_name] => Create Settings
                )
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [menu_name] => Edit Settings
                )                    
            )
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [category_name] => Users
            [category_icon] => 
            [whole_menu_table_as_array] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [menu_name] => Create Users
                )                   
            )
        )
)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT cat.id, cat.category_name, cat.category_icon, men.id, men.menu_name 
FROM `menu_categories` AS cat 
INNER JOIN menu AS men on cat.id = men.menu_category_id 
WHERE cat.user_role_id = 3 GROUP BY men
```

Comment: only if you sort your result and then make it in php yourself

Comment: is it possible via mysql only?

Comment: MySQL doesn't support any array data type. You could build a JSON document with the nested collections, but you'd still have to use PHP code to explode that JSON into a data structure after fetching it from the database. There is no way to produce a result set like you show using SQL only.

Comment: I wrote an example of using `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` for nested results here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75617520/20860 It's not exactly like your example, but it shows the technique.

Comment: Here's another example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74007308/20860